# Approximate previous year for each row

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe that has the following sample rows:

```
Product Date        Revenue
A       2021-05-10  20
A       2021-03-20  10
A       2020-01-10  5
A       2020-03-10  6
A       2020-04-10  7
```

For each product and date, I'd like to get the closest date to last year from its original date. For example, the first row's date is 2021-05-10 the closest to the previous year for this date is 2020-04-10. The resulting output I'd like is the following:

```
Product Date        Revenue   PrevDate  PrevRevenue
A       2021-05-10  20        2020-04-10   7
A       2021-03-20  10        2020-03-10   6
A       2020-01-10  5         null         null
A       2020-03-10  6         null         null
A       2020-04-10  7         null         null
```

Answer (score 0):

Say `df` is your dataframe

```
data = [['A', '2021-05-10', 20],
        ['A', '2021-03-20', 10],
        ['A', '2020-01-10', 5],
        ['A', '2020-03-10', 6],
        ['A', '2020-04-10', 7]]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, "Product:string, Date:string, Revenue:long")
df.show()

# +-------+----------+-------+
# |Product|      Date|Revenue|
# +-------+----------+-------+
# |      A|2021-05-10|     20|
# |      A|2021-03-20|     10|
# |      A|2020-01-10|      5|
# |      A|2020-03-10|      6|
# |      A|2020-04-10|      7|
# +-------+----------+-------+
```

then you can get a-year-ago-today date using `add_months` function, join dataframe with itself to get the combination of *date-last_year*, rank *prevDate* using `row_number` function over a window ordered by number of days between *last_year* and *prevDate*, then filter to get the nearest date.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, add_months, row_number, datediff
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

df = (df
      .withColumn('last_year', add_months(col('Date'), -12))
      .join(df.selectExpr('Product pr', 'Date prevDate', 'Revenue prevRevenue'),
            [col('Product') == col('pr'), col('last_year') > col('prevDate')],
            'left')
      .withColumn('closest', row_number().over(Window
                                               .partitionBy('product', 'date')
                                               .orderBy(datediff(col('last_year'), col('prevDate')))))
      .filter('closest = 1')
      .drop(*['pr', 'closest'])
      )
df.show()

# +-------+----------+-------+----------+----------+-----------+
# |Product|      Date|Revenue| last_year|  prevDate|prevRevenue|
# +-------+----------+-------+----------+----------+-----------+
# |      A|2020-01-10|      5|2019-01-10|      null|       null|
# |      A|2020-03-10|      6|2019-03-10|      null|       null|
# |      A|2020-04-10|      7|2019-04-10|      null|       null|
# |      A|2021-03-20|     10|2020-03-20|2020-03-10|          6|
# |      A|2021-05-10|     20|2020-05-10|2020-04-10|          7|
# +-------+----------+-------+----------+----------+-----------+
```